# screen brightness dimmer

Tags: display, brightness, contrast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjust screen brightness automaticly at night.](https://superuser.com/questions/149715/adjust-screen-brightness-automaticly-at-night)

Can you recommend a software to dim laptop screen brightness-contrast easily an/or predefined values?
Thank you

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: you can use "gamma panel" and save the color profiles with the hotkeys of your choice