# Auto-adjust (dim) the color scheme of the monitor at night?

Tags: display, colors, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjust screen brightness automatically at night](https://superuser.com/questions/149715/adjust-screen-brightness-automatically-at-night)

Some days spending a whole day in front of the monitor may be more strenuous on the eyes than desirable. In order to mitigate the problem I have done several things such as reducing the brightness of the monitor and using paler and darker colors where possible (such as non-white background for web pages).

That helps, but once I noticed that the "6.5K" color scheme (sometimes labeled "reading" in monitor settings) works even better than dark backgrounds and reduced brightness.

I was wondering if there is anything I can use to auto-adjust the temperature of the colors without going through the awkward monitor menu.

Both Windows and nix* specific answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) - from the page -

> it makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day